# how to use InputNumber.ValueChanged?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I'm trying to use 2-way binding between a form and my object. I can get it to work for `InputText`. But i get this errors when i add the `ValueChanged` attribute for `InputNumber`:

> CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type
> because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
> convertible to the delegate return type
>
> CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'method group' to
> 'EventCallback'

When i compile this `Component.razor` page:

```
@page "/test"

@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<EditForm Model="@model">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <InputText Value="@model.Street" ValueExpression="@(() => model.Street)" ValueChanged="@StreetChanged" />
    <InputNumber Value="@model.HouseNr" ValueExpression="@(() => model.HouseNr)" ValueChanged="@HouseNrChanged" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    protected void StreetChanged(string? value)
    {
        // ... code to lookup address and fill other fields
        model.Street = value;
    }

    protected void HouseNrChanged(int? value)
    {
        // ... code to lookup address and fill other fields
        model.HouseNr = value;
    }

    private Address model { get; set; } = new();

    class Address
    { 
        [Required]
        public string? Street { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int? HouseNr { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tried to changing my `HouseNrChanged` method, but i can't figure it out. It seems to have something to do with the different types of the `ValueChanged` properties:

- InputText.ValueChanged has type `EventCallback<string>`
- InputText.ValueChanged has type `EventCallback<TValue>`

**Questions:**

- Any ideas on how to fix this?
- Is there any documentation?
- What does ValueExpression do besides causing a runtime error when it is
  omitted?

It's very hard to find examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor - cannot convert from 'method group' to 'EventCallback'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308947/blazor-cannot-convert-from-method-group-to-eventcallback)

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos i read that earlier, but i didn't see how it is similar at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the type of the generic `EventCallback<TValue>` cannot be inferred. You have to set the `TValue` property on the `InputNumber`

```
<InputNumber TValue="int?" Value="@model.HouseNr" ValueExpression="@(() => model.HouseNr)" ValueChanged="@HouseNrChanged" />
```

Comment: thanks! that solved it. if you know any documentation that explains this then please share it